# Breakpoints not working when booting from Flash

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, stm32

In the past, I have been debugging executables loaded in the internal SRAM of my Cortex M3 (STM32F2) without problems. I have recently been loading my executable to Flash (because of size issues).

Ever since, debugging with GDB has not been working. As I understand, when the executable is in Flash, only hardware breakpoint can be used  (as opposed to software breakpoints), and I have six hardware breakpoints. However, when setting just one hardware breakpoint GDB yields an error message:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x800019a: file src/main.c, line 88.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only addresses.
(gdb) Warning:
Cannot insert hardware breakpoint 1.
Could not insert hardware breakpoints:
You may have requested too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints.
```

What could be going wrong? Have my hardware breakpoints be taken in the background?

*Note*: I used OpenOCD to load the executable through JTAG.

Comment: Have you tried creating your breakpoints with `hbreak`?

Comment: @ams: Yes, I've tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: What does `maintenance info breakpoints` say?

Comment: @ams: It says "No breakpoints or watchpoints."

Comment: That should rule out hidden background breakpoint then.

Comment: The following post to the gdb patch mailing list may be use/interest http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2006-11/msg00002.html Check which version of GDB that you are using, try to determine if the referenced patch in the above post is included in your version. Consider upgrading *if* appropriate to do so.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks. The symptoms described in the patch is exactly what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Randomblue hopefullt it may lead you down a path to resolution. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, there's basically two ways (plus one really bad way) that breakpoints can be implemented on any given debugger/platform combination:

1. Use some hardware capabilities ("hardware breakpoints") to cause the processor to trap when it hits a particular address. This is typically restricted to just a couple of breakpoints, if it's available at all.
2. For each breakpoint that's being set, replace the instruction at the breakpoint with a "trap" instruction of some variety (i.e, an instruction that will break into the debugger). When one of the breakpoints is hit, swap the original instruction back in and single-step once to make it run.
3. Single-step through the whole program. This one doesn't really count, because it's horrifically slow.

It sounds as though your debugger is only using method #2 ("software breakpoints"). The gotcha with this method is that it requires the program to be writable -- and flash memory isn't writable one instruction at a time, so this technique won't work.